# update part of the page after unobtrusive ajax post on Razor Pages

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, post, razor-pages

I have Razor Pages with one form. It posts data and set some status message. Post is done via ajax unobtrusive way. However, in this way status message is never appeared on the page. Can you, please, guide me how this Update is done on Razor Pages?

**HTML part**

```
<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#loading">
   <div class="form-group">
        <input id="code" asp-for="Code" type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
</form>

// I need to update this part
<div class="result">
    Result
    <span class="message">@Model.CheckMessage</span>
</div>
```

**Backend part**

```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
     
        [Required]
        [BindProperty]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public string CheckMessage { get; set; }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
          this.CheckMessage = "Test"; // how to make this work
          return Page();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly,you need use `data-ajax-update` to update the response from the server.

Then,the response from the server should not be `return Page()`,this will give the whole page html,what you want is only `<span class="message">@Model.CheckMessage</span>`.So you need create a partial view.

Follow the steps below:

- Create a partial view named `_Partial.cshtml`(**Note**:razor view instead of razor pages) in `Pages/Shared` folder:

  ```
  @model IndexModel
  <span class="message">@Model.CheckMessage</span>
  ```
- Change your razor pages like below:

  ```
                       //add data-ajax-url and data-ajax-update.....
  <form method="post" data-ajax-url="Index" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-update="#result" data-ajax-loading="#loading">
       <div class="form-group">
           <input id="code" asp-for="Code" type="text" class="form-control" />
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
  </form>
  <div id="result">       //change class to id....
       Result
   </div>

   @section scripts{
       <script src="~/lib/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
   }
  ```
- Backend:

  ```
  [Required]
  [BindProperty]
  public string Code { get; set; }

  [ViewData]
  public string CheckMessage { get; set; }

  public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
  {
       this.CheckMessage = "Test"; 
       return new PartialViewResult
       {
           ViewName = "_Partial",
           ViewData = this.ViewData
       };
  }
  ```

Result:

[image]